# Paragraph counter starts at 0 and doesn't count up

Tags: numbering, paragraphs

I'd like to number some of my paragraph headings. If I use `\theparagraph`, the counter starts at zero and doesn't count up. How can I fix this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\section{Heading}
\subsection{Heading}
\subsubsection{Heading}
\paragraph{\theparagraph \quad Heading} 
\paragraph{\theparagraph \quad Heading}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is the counter `secnumdepth` (i.e., section numbering depth), which defaults to `3` in the `article` class.  To get paragraphs numbered and counted (in addition to sections, subsections, and subsubsections), just increase the default value of `secnumdepth` to `4`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\paragraph{Paragraph} 
\paragraph{Paragraph}
\end{document}
```

[image]